# Need to hide background Image on scroll down in tab menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation menu which incldues the image also like below:-
![Navigation img][1]

I need to hide the image as soon as I scroll down. I tried with the Jquery plugins but couldn't succed. here is my code of the navigation:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li id="menu1">
      <a href="#tabs-3">Clothing &<br/>Accessories
        <img src="images/home/menu1.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu2">
      <a href="#tabs-1">Home & <br/>Furniture</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu3">
      <a href="#tabs-2" style="padding-top: 19px;">Electronics</a>
    </li> 
    <li id="menu4">
      <a href="#tabs-4">Fresh Food <br/>& Groceries</a>
    </li> 
    <li id="menu5">
      <a href="#tabs-5">Fresh Food <br/>& Groceries</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu6">
      <a href="#tabs-6">Fresh Food <br/>& Groceries</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also see the **CSS** part from where the Image is coming:

```
#menu1{
     border-right: 1px solid #949494;
     background-image: url('../images/home/menu1.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 119px 13px;
    background-size: 33%;
}

#menu2{
      border-right: 1px solid #949494;
     background-image: url('../images/home/menu2.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: 100px 1px;
}
#menu3{
      border-right: 1px solid #949494;
      background-image: url('../images/home/menu3.png');
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 95px -10px;
}
```

Do let me know if you need anything else.

Also see the link of the site.

[Site][2]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried @media tag for this problem?

Comment: @user37202; No, i dont think that is required for this

Comment: What I can imagine is that you wish to hide the image and contract the menu as you go down...Do you have a fixed menu in that case..??

Comment: @Vishal: yes you got it what I want. And my menu is also fixed. See the link of my site http://dev.genuusdemo.com/bigbazaar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is hide/show the background images:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
     $('#tabs li').css('background','none');
    } else {
       $('#tabs li').css('background','');
    }
});
```

---

Demo below

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
     $('#tabs li').css('background','none');
    } else {
       $('#tabs li').css('background','');
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 2000px;
} 
#menu1
  {
     border-right: 1px solid #949494;
     background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 119px 13px;
    background-size: 33%;
  }

  #menu2
   {
      border-right: 1px solid #949494;
     background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: 100px 1px;
   }
   #menu3
    {
      border-right: 1px solid #949494;
      background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200');
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 95px -10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li id="menu1"><a href="#tabs-3">Clothing &<br/>Accessories<img src="images/home/menu1.png"> </a></li>
            <li id="menu2"><a href="#tabs-1">Home & <br/>Furniture</a></li>
            <li id="menu3"><a href="#tabs-2" style="padding-top: 19px;">Electronics</a></li> 
            <li id="menu4"><a href="#tabs-4">Fresh Food <br/>& Groceries</a></li> 
            <li id="menu5"><a href="#tabs-5">Fresh Food <br/>& Groceries</a></li>
            <li id="menu6"><a href="#tabs-6">Fresh Food <br/>& Groceries</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1jfj7064/1/)

Comment: That woudn't make any difference. Are you including JQuery and wrapping the above in a document ready block?

Comment: If I paste my code in to the console on your page it works. What isn't working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66734/discussion-between-priyanka-and-uwopepisdn).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, no need to plugin, use [scrolltop](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/):

```
(function(){

   var wsSrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   var offsetTopLimit = 0;

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= offsetTopLimit) {
        $('#menu2').fadeOut();
    };

 })()
```

You need to call it also in scrolling the window.

[Here is the UPDATED fiddle](http://jsbin.com/fokajo/3/edit).

Comment: Now it should! Check UPDATED fiddle.

Comment: Have you check the http://jsbin.com/fokajo/3/ ? the element #menu2 is hiddem as load the page, because offsetTopLimit = 0; change it as you have to.

Comment: Yes checked and it was not working. How to change it as per mine ?

Comment: You can change offsetTopLimit as a static height, for example 100, or have it from the dom, get the nev height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66741/discussion-between-priyanka-and-giacomo-paita).

Answer (score 0):

do you need something like this?

put the image as background of the div and set `background-attachment: fixed;`

```css
.test1 {
    background-image: url(http://www.64k.it/andres/data/test_video/TestCard.gif);
    height: 400px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.test2 {
    height: 800px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1"></div>
<div class="test2">Bye bye</div>
```

**update**

try in this way

```
.classTest{
   background-image: none;
}
```

then check for scroll event with jquery

```
var delta = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > delta){
       // scroll down remove class classTest
   } else {
      // scroll up add background image when reach the top of the page (or top + image height)


      if($(window).scrollTop() ==0) {
       // alert("top!"); add background image class
      }

   }
   delta = st;
});
```

Comment: I have a menu which includes images and the menus are fixed, and I want to hide the images when I scroll down. that is what i want. The above code is not related to what I want

Answer (score 0):

On mobile -- but what you want to do is $.on "scroll", if you're not at scrollTop=0 (for the main object being scrolled), apply a new class ($.addClass) to your items that have the background image in them.

This new class is simply:

`.newclass {background-image:none !important}`

Also check that when you do reach scrollTop 0, you $.removeClass your new class, so the images show back up.

If you want to add some pretty to it, in your newclass, use a CSS3 transition for like .25s or so.

Comment: can you also write the js for that as I am not getting your point. Please see the link as my site is http://dev.genuusdemo.com/bigbazaar/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `background-image` you can just add an image in your `<li>`.

Then use the `$(window).scrollTop()` to know if you are at the top or not, then show or hide your `<img>` using conditional statement.... *example below:*

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 60) { //where 60 is the height of your header
        $('img').fadeOut('fast');    // or you can keep it 0 as well, no issues..
    } else {
        $('img').fadeIn('fast');
    }
});
```

well the rest of the **Demo** is [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/1jfj7064/3/)

Tell if this works for you....

Good luck :)

Comment: where to add the image as, can you give me one example of that

Comment: I've seen your site... you can hide the background-image as well and then decrease your width of each <li> to shrink it, as it happens in a lower resolution..

Comment: it is hiding all the image of the site. I want to hide the background Image of the navigation only

Comment: Ah, ok, add / remove a class instead of $('#menu2').fadeOut(); in my code! :-)

Comment: i changed as per my code tag in html. It works. Thanks